# Value assigned to variable differs from value printed directly

Tags: c++

In a part of my code, I have

```
a = cache[k1][k2][k3][k4];
cout << "DEBUG: " << a << " " << cache[k1][k2][k3][k4] << endl;
```

And my cout has the following output:

```
DEBUG: 38 38
DEBUG: 3 3
DEBUG: 37 37
DEBUG: 4 35 <- the problem
```

I don't understand what in the world is going on.

a,k1,k2,k3,k4 are integers and cache is a

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<int> > > >
```

Comment: There is nothing threaded. This is a regular program.

Comment: I know this seems silly, but are you sure that this "DEBUG" output is being generated by this part of the code? Maybe there are other "DEBUG" lines.

Comment: It is the only cout in the code with DEBUG. I have even stepped through the code in VS and witnessed it output.

Comment: Does it happen when you run the code outside debugger (Ctrl+F5 in VS)?

Comment: You removed something you didn't consider important, but is the actual cause of your problem.  Please provide a minimal, yet compiling example that demonstrates your problem.  A way to do this is to first duplicate your source tree, recompile, make sure it still occurs -- then start paring it down.  At each stage, recompile and see if the problem still occurs.  Make a backup of each stage where the problem still occurs.  Either you'll end up with a minimal example of the problem, or the problem will disappear while paring it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this could occur is if one of the indexes is out of bounds and so you're accessing memory that's outside of the vectors. The vector member function `at` works just like a subscript operator except that it does bounds checking, use it to detect this error.

```
a = cache.at(k1).at(k2).at(k3).at(k4);
```

Comment: I changed both the assignment and output statement to use four at(), and there is still a discrepancy as well as no error statements.

Comment: @user904963, are any of the indexes reference variables? That's the only other possibility I can think of.